# Best Practice to manage Routes in Flutter as bellow route graph

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, nested-routes

I'm struggling on structure of my routes. Hoping get help to sort it out. Bellow image represent my route tree. I would like to get to know best way to handle these kind of situations.

[image]

I'm currently using `IndexedStack` to manage the bottom navigation and I have added `Navigator Widget` to manage screen inside **Explore** Tab. However I can't open **Search Result** Screen from **Home** Screen.

I have doubt the way I use this navigation structure. Does anyone have suggestions ?

Comment: What's the error you are getting when pushing `Search Result` Screen from `Home` ?

Comment: I can open the explore Home with bottom navigation index. But I couldn't find a way to call Search result from HOME.